# How to map subclass and subclass properties in NHibernate and C#

Tags: c#, xml, nhibernate

**How to map this type of subclass container situation in Nhibernate.** Help me providing the mapping xml structure

*My Class Strucutre*

```
public class Employee
{
    public virtual int EmpID;
    public virtual string EmpName;
    public virtual Audit AuditDetails;
}

public class Audit
{
    public virtual User CreatedBy;
    public virtual DateTime CreatedOn;
    public virtual User ModifiedBy;
    public virtual DateTime ModifiedOn;
}

public class User
{
    public virtual int UserID;
    public virtual string FullName;
    public virtual Audit AuditDetails;
}
```

*My database table structure*

```
Employee
EmpID(int pk) | EmpName(varchar) | CreatedBy(int) | ModifiedBy(int) | CreatedOn(date) | ModifiedOn(date)

User
UserID (int pk) | FullName(varchar) | CreatedBy(int) | ModifiedBy(int) | CreatedOn(date) | ModifiedOn(date)
```

Using **NHibernate** and **C#** I wish to solve this situation.
Most of my tables contain the **Audit detials** (creator, Modifier and datetimes of them)
I wish to map in such a way that the **Userid** should be saved as the **CreatedBy** and **ModifiedBy** fields and for Dates is a direct mapping.
But those all details is a seperate entity called **Audit** in my class structure.
Please help me by providing a mapping sheet for this type of situation.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I dont know the naming 'subclass' is correct here. but my doubt was cleared by the details given by "Rytmis". Next is how to map the UserID of the User into the CreatedBy and ModifiedBy field. I will google side by side also...

Comment: Imho you are trying to build https://bitbucket.org/RogerKratz/nhibernate.envers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put your Audit entity in the same tables, you will need to use `<component>`. Here's a tutorial:

http://ayende.com/blog/3937/nhibernate-mapping-component